# Losing accents with for loop in Python

Tags: python, eclipse, string, diacritics

When I use the next code in Python:

```
line = "áaáaáaá"
for c in line:
    print c
```

My out is:

�
�
a
�
�
a
�
�
a
�
�

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which python version are you on? Where are you running this?

Comment: I think it can be related to the settings of your console, can you please specify what terminal emulator you use?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.3 on Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've googled a bit on this problem, i found something here:

http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/02/21/pro-tip-unicode-characters-in-the-eclipse-console/

Try going from the Launch Configuration dialog > Common > and set the encoding to `utf-8` or `latin-1`.

If this doesn't solve the problem, try converting each character to `utf-8` format and then print it:

```
line = unicode("áaáaáaá", encoding="utf-8")
for c in line:
    print c
```

Edit: Here's some explanation :)

When you don't specify the encoding as `utf-8`, the interpreter breaks it down in wrong parts. For example, `à` is stored as '\xc3\xa1`. In the loop, python thinks of it as two separate characters:

```
>>> s = "áaáaáaá".encode()
>>> for i, c in enumerate(s):
    print(i,c)


0 195
1 161
2 97
3 195
4 161
5 97
6 195
7 161
8 97
9 195
10 161
```

It thinks of `\xc3\xa1` as two chars, which is:

```
Ã
¡
```

Why does it works when you specify the encoding, then? Well, i'm sure you got it already. When you set the encoding to `utf-8`, it treats the string with the format of `utf-8`, and it knows that `\xc3\xa1` is one character.

Well, in my second method, it would work even if you don't set the encoding to `utf-8`. Why? Because this:

```
line = unicode("áaáaáaá", encoding="utf-8")
```

converts the encoding from `utf-8` to what your interpreter uses.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried now, look:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: unexpected end of data

Comment: oh, using my latter solution? Hang on, i'll fix it.

Comment: By the way, while using your method with the encoding changed, did you get it to work?

Comment: Your solution works, but I changed "latin-1" to "utf-8". Now is fixed. Tahk you very much.

Comment: Your answer works, but it does not explain what is actually going on. Also, the problem has nothing to do with the console.

Comment: @JonasWielicki I've updated it with some explanation, please correct me if i'm wrong somewhere :D

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following on python interpretor to understand , hope this findings helps you !

> ```
> \> line = "áaáaáaá"
> \> line
> '\xc3\xa1a\xc3\xa1a\xc3\xa1a\xc3\xa1'
> ```

This entire line was store as a utf-16 . Note `á` is converted into `\xc3\xa1`

```
line = "áaáaáaá"
for c in line:
    print c
```

The split of line happens like this -  `'\xc3' , '\xa1', 'a' , '\xc3' ....`
and this the output is something like `� � a � � a � � a � �`

So if you specify something like this -

```
\> line = unicode("áaáaáaá", encoding="utf-8")
\> line
u'\xe1a\xe1a\xe1a\xe1'
```

This will encode the unicode value of all characters in single byte itself.

Now the split of line happens like this - `'\xe1', a, '\xe1', 'a', '\xe1', 'a', ...`

and output is something like `áaáaáaá`